# ReactNative expo app crna entry Bundle exception after redux state dispatch

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

I do not know what to call for this strange exception the way the exception message printed on my console is not giving any hint and any meaningful message. Hence I am not able to put a proper title for the exception.

The app is developed using Expo and Redux state manager 
I am getting following exception after dispatching the state.

Interesting observations :

1. The action is appropriate and payload has valid JSON value.
2. When I print payload in reducer it is printing proper values

Here is the code

```
axios.post('API PATH', reqBody)
  .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: CAMPAIGNS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data.campaigns
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('error occured while fetching campaigns: ', JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

For the above code, as soon as I dispatch the control goes to reducer as well and reducer is printing proper values but after that I am getting following exception

```
    error occured while fetching campaigns: , {"line":163362,"column":43,"sourceURL":"http://packager.kk.camp.exp.direct:80/./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false"}
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/YellowBox.js:67:16 in error
* src/screens/CampaignActions/
CampaignActions.js:125:22 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:295:23 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:148:6 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:196:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:464:11 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:282:4 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:137:6 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:269:6 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:136:17 in flushedQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:11 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Any help ? Its taking lot of time for me.

Comment: It's dangerous to dispatch the payload as you are doing. The response.data can be undefined, so will throw an error. You should check if you really have response.data before dispatching this action

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this, but not sure about few things, let me put it here and expecting some comments for further understanding.

I have two components say Component1 and Component2 , each has its own state, say ComponentState1 and ComponentState2 and two reducers ComponentReducer1 and ComponentReducer2.

In my both states there is one common json array, say Campaigns[] is common in both component states. When I load Component2 it was crashing, then I removed action for campaigns from Component1, which means ComponentReducer1 and ComponentReducer2 both have one common action say Campaign_Fetch_Success, I removed this from Component1 then the crash was resolved, but I need campaigns in Component1 also so for that I dispatched different action and this will be dispatched only when component1 will be loaded, say something like Campaign_Fetch_For_Component1_Success.

Now the problem is solved but why it was crashing when we have same actions for both component reducers that is putting me still in puzzle ?